Deploying Flask / Angular app _from the same repository_ to Heroku
I have an existing app written in Flask, deployed to Heroku, It works great, but I decided to convert it to an Angular frontend, using Flask just for the API. This also works great locally, but I'm almost done and I'd like deploy it to Heroku from the same repository. This site is an internal set of tools and is SUPER low traffic...think 20-40 hits a day MAX.
This is the current file system structure:
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── backend
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── static **(will not be used by Flask)**
│   └── templates **(will not be used by Flask)**
├── frontend
│   ├── angular.json
│   ├── dist
│   │   ├── mmscripts
│   │   │   ├── 3rdpartylicenses.txt
│   │   │   └── browser
│   │   │   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   │   │   ├── index.html
│   │   │   │   ├── main-HX6HQ3LL.js
│   │   │   │   ├── polyfills-S3BTP7ME.js
│   │   │   │   └── styles-HCXVZOOP.css
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── app
│   │   │   ├── env.ts
│   │   ├── assets
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── main.ts
│   │   └── styles.scss
│   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── tsconfig.spec.json
└── runtime.txt

At the moment I cd into backend and run the Flask app: FLASK_ENV=development flask run
Then in a separate shell I cd into frontend and run ng serve. I have Flask-Cors installed in the Flask app so that Angular can access the API, then in frontend/src/app/env.ts I've got this constant:
export const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api';

Here's some versioning:
Angular 17
Flask 3
Flask-Cors 4
Heroku stack is 22

Procfile:
web: gunicorn app:app

runtime.txt
python-3.9.19

I don't mind rearranging the file system if need be. I just used this particular setup because it seemed to make things easier from an organizational standpoint.

It's not clear how you want to deploy it. The simplest from a topology (and e.g. CORS, which you then wouldn't need to handle) perspective is just to get the Flask app to serve the static outputs of the ng build - you certainly don't want to be running the dev server in production.

Hey Jon, that's part of my question. I'm solid with the writing of the software, but the deploying of it is still something I'm learning. The current live version has everything in the root folder, then I deploy to Heroku with a simple git push heroku main. I'd love to keep it that simple if possible, but I expect I might need to write a deploy script via Make or npm which bundles everything, then pushes it up. Do you have suggestions?

I guess what I'm asking is 1) Is this possible? 2) If so, what changes do I need to make to the current organization (and/or code) to allow me to implement this?

I was able to get this working almost exactly like I was hoping.
For anyone coming behind me, here's how I accomplished it.

Create backend and a frontend directories.

Flask code goes in the backend directory as shown above.
Angular code goes in the frontend directory as shown above.


In the root of the project, create a Procfile which contains the below code.

web: gunicorn --chdir ./backend app:app
In my case I'm using gunicorn, if you're using another server, the approach might be different.


In the frontend directory, prior to deploying to Heroku, run the following command:

ng build --configuration production
A dist folder should either be created, or updated, with your minimized Angular code.



In order to allow Flask to serve the proper files, I also had to make changes to my app.py file as follows:
from flask import (
    Flask,
    send_from_directory,
)

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../frontend/dist/<my Angular app name>/browser/', static_url_path='')

@app.errorhandler(404)
@app.route('/',defaults={"e": ""})
def index(e):
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=81)

